# how can i get the token our from a plain string with regex?

Tags: regex

I want to extract token from this string :

`"token":"THIS IS A TEST TOKEN","_persist":"{"version":-1,"rehydrated":true}"}`

something like this :

`"token":"THIS IS A TEST TOKEN"`

how can i do that with regexp?

i dont know the solution

Answer (score 0):

use following regex

```
"token":"(?<token>.*)",
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/AFXkaq/1)